# Accompanist FlowRow : is it possible to scroll down automatically in order to show an element?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

In my Jetpack Compose project, one of my components uses a `FlowRow` from [Accompanist](https://github.com/google/accompanist).
But I don't know how to make the `FlowRow` scroll to a given "node".

Here the relevant code from my `@Composable`:

```kotlin
sealed class MovesNavigatorElement(open val text: String)
data class MoveNumber(override val text: String) : MovesNavigatorElement(text)
data class HalfMoveSAN(override val text: String) : MovesNavigatorElement(text)

@Composable
fun MovesNavigator(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, elements: Array<MovesNavigatorElement>, mustBeVisibleByDefaultElementIndex: Int) {
    val vertScrollState = rememberScrollState()

    FlowRow(
        modifier = modifier
            .background(color = Color.Yellow.copy(alpha = 0.3f))
            .verticalScroll(vertScrollState),
        mainAxisSpacing = 10.dp,
        crossAxisSpacing = 15.dp,
    ) {
        elements.map {
            Text(text = it.text, fontSize = 34.sp, color = Color.Blue, style= MaterialTheme.typography.body1)
        }
    }
}
```

Where you can see that I declare the "nodes" of the `FlowRow` as a list : the parameter `elements`. Also I'm using a `ScrollState` in the local variable `vertScrollState`.

But, let's say that I want to make it scroll to `elements[30]` : how should I do that ? Given that `mustBeVisibleByDefaultElementIndex` is the index of the element that **must** be visible **by default**. I mean, when composition occurs. But **the user can change the position later** of course.

In other words :

1. At composition : the element whose index is given is made visible
2. Then, before any other composition occurs of course, the user can scroll it **with the scrollbar**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how I manage to solve (partially) my issue :

1. use a plain `ScrollState` instead of `rememberScrollState()` : because even if I set scroll to a fixed value at recomposition, the user still will be able to move it. So, no need to "cache" the scroll value
2. use sp to px conversion for the scroll amount which is expected a value in pixels, and an hard-coded division amount of the given index  (that's why it is only partially solved)

Which led me to the following :

```kotlin
sealed class MovesNavigatorElement(open val text: String)
data class MoveNumber(override val text: String) : MovesNavigatorElement(text)
data class HalfMoveSAN(override val text: String) : MovesNavigatorElement(text)

@Composable
fun MovesNavigator(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, elements: Array<MovesNavigatorElement>, mustBeVisibleByDefaultElementIndex: Int = 0) {
    val lineHeightPixels = with(LocalDensity.current) {34.sp.toPx()}
    val scrollAmount = ((mustBeVisibleByDefaultElementIndex / 6) * lineHeightPixels).toInt()
    val vertScrollState = ScrollState(scrollAmount)

    FlowRow(
        modifier = modifier
            .background(color = Color.Yellow.copy(alpha = 0.3f))
            .verticalScroll(vertScrollState),
        mainAxisSpacing = 8.dp,
    ) {
        elements.map {
            Text(text = it.text, fontSize = 34.sp, color = Color.Blue, style= MaterialTheme.typography.body1)
        }
    }
}
```

But still have to test on several devices.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the method parameter,

`val state = rememberScrollState(initial = mustBeVisibleByDefault)`

Better press `Ctrl` + `P` to see all possible combinations before going to even the web.

**I kept this in case if anyone finds it helpful bizarrely:-**

The `ScrollState` exposes `scrollTo` and `animateScrollTo` methods. You can easily use them to achieve the desired result. Refer to [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary#rememberScrollState(kotlin.Int))

Comment: Yes, I've seen those methods from the documentation. Thank you. But how could I target a specific element ? I mean how could I get the position of a given element registered in the `FlowRow` ? In my question, I said that I will pass the targeted element index in a parameter.

If possible, of course.

Comment: It is unclear. Parameter to what? If you want it to be a parameter to the MovesNavigator Composable, either you are confused with how declarative programming works, or you have a specific use-case which is not completely portrayed by the question. Just add a simple image of the expected layout and explain the behaviour in layman terms? The problem with most askers is that they send out technical questions asking for how to make an approach work, whereas if you post the use-case, we might be able to suggest a simpler and better approach altogether.

Comment: You want it to scroll to a position when? Is it that you want it to load at a particular index?

Comment: Or scroll using some navigators or something. Just post the use-case

Comment: I've added a parameter `mustBeVisibleElementIndex`

Comment: That doesn't clear up much.

Comment: You want a particular item visible that's okay, but... it's weird can't you just add a human-readable description to it?

Comment: It says `must`BeVisible. You want it to be always visible even if the user scrolls past it?

Comment: Just edit the question sir

Comment: Your question does not delineate your concern AT ALL!

Comment: That is the problem

Comment: I do not know WHAT your concern is

Comment: I recognize my question missed many precisions : I've tried to fix that some time ago.

Comment: Oh! You should have said so. Now it is clear

Comment: Sorry, but your solution is not yet what I'm trying to solve : you're initializing the scroll position with the index of the "node" to target. That's not enough.

Comment: Then what's enough? You don't specify anything other than that in your post

Comment: Sir you do realise that the only way to convey your info to people over at stackoverflow is by actually typing it in your question?

Comment: I think that my question has already clarified what I want

Comment: That's it! I'm calling the police!

Comment: Woah woah woah, calm down sir. All I am saying, is that your question does not convey exactly what your are trying to achieve here. We are actually here to help, but if the required details are well submitted, it would be easier. You see, questions usually receive answers by this time, but this one hasn't, since it lacks clarity. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It was a little joke. Meant no disrespect. I would still say you actually update the question with a valid use-case.

Comment: I can't see how I can be more clear this time. If my question cannot be answered, I'm ready to give up now.

Comment: Ok wait up a moment

Comment: You want the row to scroll to a given node. You did not mention exactly WHEN do you want it to happen. A button click? Some other triggers? How am I supposed to know where to put the scrolling code?

Comment: Yeah so the answer I provided will do exactly the same. It will scroll to the item numbered `mustBeVisibleByDefault` at the first composition, then retain whichever position the user decides to scroll to

Comment: What is the issue that did not get resolved? Please try to run once if you haven't.

Comment: Hello? Sir? You there!?

Comment: Yes. As I am still stuck with my issue, I think the best would be to go on with the SO chat

Comment: I have opened a session, but I don't play well with SO chat. This is convenient.

Comment: I'm asking you because we are "flooding" the topic with comments

Comment: Yeah I've opened the session, but just tell me what the issue is, currently

Comment: You should be able to scroll to the default upon composition. What do you want next?

Comment: You can log [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238943/discussion-between-loloof64-and-marsk)